# Fontawesome webfonts sometimes not loading since webpack build

Tags: webpack, sass, font-awesome, webpack-5

I just migrated the old css and js build process in our project from grunt (and css in less) to webpack 5 (and css in scss) and everything seems fine. There is one problem, however:
Sometimes instead of looking like this

[image: how it looks normally]

Here's what the heart looks like in DevTools:

```
.fa-heart:before {
    content: "";
}
```

the fontawesome webfonts don't seem to be loading correctly and instead load in like this

[image: completely broken]

The heart looks like this when I inspect it in DevTools

```
.fa-heart:before {
    content: "ï€„";
}
```

I would have expected to see

```
.fa-heart:before {
    content: "\f004";
}
```

and when I change it to that manually in the DevTools, it works.

This can be reproduced when I start a lighthouse audit in my browser: The very last load when lighthouse is done will always look like this.

I have honestly no idea what to even google about this problem.
I tried using [webfontloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfontloader) to load the font but this did not help with the problem.

I am including fontawesome like this in my main.scss:

```
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/light";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/solid";
```

Here's a simplified (fewer entries) version of my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    './dist/styles.min': { import: './src/sass/main.scss' },
    './dist/scripts.min.js': { import: './src/js/scripts.js' },
  }
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: require.resolve("jquery"),
        loader: "expose-loader",
        options: {
          exposes: ["$", "jQuery", "jquery"],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { debug: false, useBuiltIns: "usage", corejs: 3 }], "@babel/preset-react"],
            plugins: [["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", { corejs: 3 }]],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /(ignore)/,
        use: {
          loader: "ignore-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ttf|eot|woff2?)$/i,
        use: [
           {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              outputPath: "dist/assets/",
              publicPath: "/assets/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "[name]?[contenthash]",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css?[contenthash]",
    }),
  ],
optimization: {
    minimize: !DEV_MODE,
    minimizer: [
      "...",
      new TerserPlugin({ extractComments: false }),
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        polyfills: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](@babel|core-js|regenerator|promise)/,
          name: "./dist/polyfills.min.js",
          chunks: "all",
        },
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](slick|bootstrap|jquery)/,
          name: "./dist/vendor.min.js",
          chunks: "all",
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`"\f004"` [is actually equivalent to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60266415/scss-webfont-font-awesome-compilation-corruption-using-webpack) `""`, but the character `"ï€„"` may be occurring because your CSS is missing the `@charset "UTF-8"` rule. It could be getting stripped during minimizing.

It may be happening in the terser-webpack-plugin [(see this issue)](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/107). You can try adding the following to your web pack config:

```
TerserPlugin({
  terserOptions: { output: { ascii_only: true } }
})
```

More information: https://medium.com/@thinkpanda_75045/webpack-with-unicode-7a2c5eb22afd

Similar issue: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/17644

Comment: Thanks for linking similar issues. I tried your suggestions as well as many of the proposed ones in your links. What helped was [to downgrade to `sass@1.10.4`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/17644#issuecomment-796114103), which does not transform the escape sequences to their unicode equivalents

Answer (score 1):

*To determine if this solution will fix your specific issue, you can follow **step 10**, which provides a straightforward method for testing.

The following is a detailed explanation of how I resolved the issue of weird icons and obtained the correct outcome, using the "fa-user" icon (Unicode \f007) as an example, which is one of the most frequently used icons on websites:

Before:[enter image description here][1]

After:[enter image description here][2]

What I tried: A suggestion to add  was already present on the site. Adding @charset 'utf-8' to the top of my fontawesome.scss did not resolve the issue of weird icons, **This was because the @charset declaration was being removed during compile time.**

We are currently self-hosting fontawesome icons using their fontawesome-subset feature to reduce the file size, and using Sass 1.58.3, sass-loader, and css-loader with Webpack 4 to compile our scss files.

Here are some steps that can be taken to verify if the icons are displaying correctly: I performed the following **steps to confirm the accuracy of the outcome**:

1. Go to the website.
2. Press Ctrl+U or right-click and select "View page source."
3. Click on the href link for the stylesheet. example:
4. Search for an icon, such as "fa-user."
5. If the issue is resolved, the icon should display the Unicode content "f007" or the correct symbol.
   [enter image description here][3]
6. If the icon displays as [?], double-check to ensure it is correct by searching for it on the web.
7. [enter image description here][4]
8. Copy and paste the [?] into a search engine to check if it appears as Unicode.
   [enter image description here][5]
9. This solution works for both fontawesome 5 and 6, as I tested it on both versions.
10. To perform a quick check and verify whether this solution will resolve the issue, you can try adding @charset "utf-8"; at the beginning of your compiled CSS file.[enter image description here][6]

**Solution:**
The solution to the issue is to add the npm package "[**add-charset-webpack-plugin**][7]". This package automatically adds the charset declaration in the first line of all final CSS files, ensuring that the UTF-8 encoding is specified and correctly interpreted by browsers.

How to apply:
In your webpack.config.js file:

1. Import package:
   import AddCharsetWebpackPlugin from 'add-charset-webpack-plugin';
2. Add Plugin into your plugins:[] section:
   new AddCharsetWebpackPlugin({
   charset: "utf-8"
   }),

Hope this helps!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pPvK.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBdFU.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHFsY.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI6EJ.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/asPO0.png
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXbZY.png
[7]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/add-charset-webpack-plugin